# Jquery Add active class to parent class

Tags: jquery

I want to make a navigation menu that will add active class when i click. Also, when child is clicked, its parent will add active class and remove the current active class(only one will be active). For example, when link 3 is clicked, link 2 and link 1 will not be active. When link 2.1 is clicked, only link 2 will be active.

```
<ul class="additional-menu">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="link2.1">Link2.1</a></li>
</ul>
<li><a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.additional-menu').on('click','li', function(){
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

});
```

Comment: your HTML is not valid, check it out and correct it.

Comment: Per the W3 docs, a nested `<ul>` should be the child of a `<li>` - https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Basically, when an anchor is clicked, it removes all the `active` classes from the root menu item. Then it adds the class `active` to all the parent `li`

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9f14qkxu/1/)

HTML (corrected from your demo)

```
<ul class="additional-menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="link2.1">Link2.1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.additional-menu a').on('click', function() {
  var t = $(this); //optional but faster if we use it more than once
  t.parents('.additional-menu').find('li').removeClass('active'); //remove all the active classes
  t.parentsUntil('.additional-menu', 'li').addClass('active'); //set the active class to all the li parents of the anchor element
})
```

Comment: Thanks!! that is what i want.

Comment: the active class not work when i put url instead of #. How to fix that? i am using the code as php:include'menu.php';

Comment: Well that depends how your page is setup. When you click on a URL, do you load another page? Or is it ajax?

Comment: When i clink on URL. It load another html/php file.

Comment: Ok. In your menu.php can you set an initial "active" class? If so, you can use this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9f14qkxu/4/

Comment: Still same. I mean after i click on a URL, the active class does not change. The active class always in the initial "active" class

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. You said that when a link is clicked, the page reloads. When it loads, your PHP script needs to add the active class to the correct list element. jQuery can not detect which link has been clicked since the page is reloaded every time. In order to pass data from page to page via javascript, it's a lot more complicated. The script I provided works. You just need to setup your menu correctly.

If you need more help, you need to share the menu.php script.

Comment: Bro, what if i want to add the class active in <a> instead of <li> ? how to modify?

Comment: @Darcy You still have to add the active class to the parent li but this is what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/9f14qkxu/5/